# Formula To Aggregate Totals for Year

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I use to keep track of climbing progress (snippet shown below). I have formulas and graphs that keep track of counts of specific grades over time, but I am having trouble with a formula to keep a running total (by year) of feet climbed. I intent to put this in another sheet.

[image]

Basically I would like a single cell that does something like ... if Sheet1!A:A begins with "21." and if Sheet1!E:E,"<>*%" (which means I actually completed the climb) then add the rows total climb length (Sheet1!J:J * Sheet1!I:I) to the running total for that year.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If column A are true dates then use a pivot table.

Comment: @ScottCraner I will give that a wag. I am in Google Sheets, but I was able to put together a pivot table, I just need to be a bit smarter about how to use it.

Comment: if Google-Sheets why the Excel tag?  Tag it appropriately and those who know Google-Sheets may be able to find a different or better route.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: So essentially you want to add all the climbs from this specific year? Do you also have dates from past year? If not, why not just simply add them using an `IF` and `SUM`? @ShaneK

Comment: @ale13, yeah I have a couple of other years, and am looking to keep a running total of feet climbed based on the type of climb (row F) for each year. I have to do some other wonky checks like making sure column E does not contain %, and if it does not adding column J*I for the running total for that type of climb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ale13 ... using your example and adding a couple of things (also needed to parseInt totals) ...

```
function calculateTotal() {
  
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let s7 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet7');
  let date = ss.getRange('A2:A').getDisplayValues();
  let type = ss.getRange('F2:F').getDisplayValues();
  let tries = ss.getRange('E2:E').getDisplayValues();
  let lengths = ss.getRange('I2:I').getDisplayValues();
  let laps = ss.getRange('J2:J').getDisplayValues();
  
  let btotal = 0;
  let rtotal = 0;
  
  for (let i =0; i<date.length; i++) {
    if (date[i][0].toString().startsWith('21') != false && tries[i][0].toString().includes('%') == false) {
       // Totals for Bouldering 
       if (type[i][0] == "B") {
         btotal = btotal + parseInt(lengths[i][0]*laps[i][0]);
       }
       // Totals for Top Rope or Sport
       else {
         rtotal = rtotal + parseInt(lengths[i][0]*laps[i][0])
       }
    }
  }
  
  console.log("Roped total = " + rtotal)
  console.log("Bouldering total = " + btotal)

  s7.getRange('B2').setValue(rtotal);
  s7.getRange('B3').setValue(btotal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Apps Script and creating a script in order to manage your task.

So for example, you might want to take a look at the snippet below:

#### Code

```
function calculateTotal() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let date = ss.getRange('A2:A').getDisplayValues();
  let tries = ss.getRange('E2:E').getDisplayValues();
  let lengths = ss.getRange('I2:I').getDisplayValues();
  let total = 0;
  for (let i =0; i<date.length; i++) {
    if (date[i][0].toString().startsWith('21') != false && tries[i][0].toString().includes('%') == false) {
       total = total+lengths[i][0];
    }
  }
  ss.getRange('M2').setValue(total);
}
```

#### Explanation

The script above gathers all the values from the `Sheet1` and loops through them. If the conditions check (the date should start with `21` and the `E` column does not contain `%`) then the corresponding length is added to the total; the total is then saved in the `M2` cell in this case.

#### Further improvement

The advantage of using a script is that it is versatile and easier to manage. In this situation, you can make use of Apps Script's time-driven triggers; so assuming you plan on updating your spreadsheet every day at a specific time, you can create a trigger which will run right after it.

For example, the below function creates a trigger for the function above which will run every day at ~9.

```
function createTrigger() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("calculateTotal")
        .timeBased()
        .atHour(9)
        .everyDays(1)
        .create();
}
```

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: Very, very helpful thanks for your input. I am working on setting up a trigger to run when the spreadsheet is modified if possible.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to grab unique dates and dump totals for each day in the same script?